# Is it appropriate to model a DC/DC converter as a variable resistance if I have input voltage and current datapoints?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, simulation, rectifier, simulink

So I am designing a circuit in MATLAB simulink which is basically a rectifier followed by a DC/DC converter.

Both simulations are working perfectly individually. However, when I attach the DC/DC converter to the rectifier the simulation becomes excruciatingly slow. It's impossible for me to analyze it.

Hence I am considering if it would be appropriate to model the DC/DC converter in a simpler way by using the current and voltage data points available from simulation of the individual DC/DC converter. Right now I am considering a variable resistor model, by dividing the input voltage by input current of the DC/DC converter at each time instant.

Will this be mathematically and electrically accurate or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you fitted a smoothing capacitor on the output of the rectifier?

Comment: @Andy aka yes there is a capacitor at the output of rectifier.

Comment: I think you need to show your circuit.

Comment: You'll probably need to help the solver, it sounds like convergence problems. Without seeing any schematic, it's impossible to say what/who/where, but you could try to add some small capacitances across the rectifier diodes (series RC snubbers), or across the nodes that have the sharpest transitions.

Comment: To a first approximation, the DC/DC converter is a constant power load, not a resistance. The rule it enforces is Vin * Iin = k where Vin is the input voltage, Iin is the input current, and k is a constant. This ignores transient response, but is reasonably true for DC behavior.

Comment: You could model that with a variable resistance, I guess.

Comment: The easiest way is to model the dc-dc converter with a constant power load which is a current source whose value is \$i(t)=\frac{P_{out}}{v_{in}(t)}\$. This mimics a converter featuring a negative incremental resistance and an infinite input voltage rejection. \$v_{in}(t)\$ represents the voltage across the current source.

Comment: @ a concerned citizen I made a detailed post today showing my exact issue: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610916/how-can-i-accurately-and-quickly-simulate-this-280ah-battery-charger-circuit-wit Could you take a look?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to model a regulating dc-dc converter is to use a constant power source. It can be modeled as a voltage-controlled current source. The instantaneous current depends on the power absorbed by the dc-dc and the voltage across the current source terminals: \$i(t)=\frac{P_{out}}{v_{in}(t)}\$ in which \$v_{in}(t)\$ represents the instantaneous voltage controlling the current and \$P_{out}\$ the power delivered by the converter. This offers the advantage of modeling a negative incremental resistance and provides a good way to check the interaction with a front-end EMI filter.

The below drawing shows a typical application in a front-end rectifier and lets you assess the ripple amplitude when the bulk capacitor is loaded by the constant-power source:

[image]

You can also use a voltage-dependent resistor called a PWL resistance in SIMPLIS. Using an Excel sheet, you compute the resistance value based on the applied voltage and considering a constant power:

[image]

The divide-by-zero case when the bulk capacitor is discharged should often be considered by adding a .IC defining an initial charge.

Comment: could you suggest a resource I could read about this from in detail? The modelling as a constant power source looks interesting.

Comment: I am not sure there are many details in the literature. I remember discussing it in my [APEC 2017](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf) seminar you can download from my site but I use it to test EMI stability which is also an important topic.

Comment: My DC/DC converter also needs to charge a battery with CC-CV control...I don't think it would be possible using this model. I made a detailed post about my exact issue today: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610916/how-can-i-accurately-and-quickly-simulate-this-280ah-battery-charger-circuit-wit . Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to model.  But a switch-mode DC/DC converter doesn't really look much like a variable resistor.

If it's stepping down the voltage, then it can deliver more current on the output than is drawn from the input.  No resistor network can do that.