# How can I accurately and quickly simulate this 280Ah battery charger circuit with a real-time charging time of over 2 hour?

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, power-factor-correction, simulink

So I am designing an on-board charger of rating 10kW in MATLAB simulink for an electric vehicle to charge a 72V, 280Ah battery with a maximum charging current of 125A. As the calculations work out, it will take over 2.2 hours to completely charge the battery. I have the individual PFC and the DC/DC converter stages ready in simulink as shown below.

Three-phase PFC rectifier stage
[image]

DC/DC converter stage (phase shifted full bridge)
[image]

Both stages work perfectly individually.
I have combined the stages as shown, PFC followed by DC/DC converter.

[image]

Now the combined charger takes insanely long to simulate, and simulink runs out of memory. I cannot scale down the Ah rating of battery as that reduces the nominal battery current as well and I cannot view the performance of the converter for the current I wish to design it for. I am unable to figure out a work around to this. I tried looking for ways to model DC/DC converter in a simpler way using small signal equivalent circuit however I am unable to do it in a way that accurately represents the PSFB converter. Any suggestions to accurately and successfully perform this simulation would be immensely helpful!

Link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d8GbrlwvKdwGhXFfrdIuI202A7UhvLQf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A simplified model of the DC/DC?

Comment: Decide what you wnat to simulate more: the PFC or the charger? If it's the PFC, you can adda constant pwer load (that would be the DC-DC). If it's the charger, just use a DC supply with a sine modulated ripple to mimic the non-constant DC. or save the ripple  from the PFC simulation and superimpose it on a DC source.

Comment: @a concerned citizen I have already simulated the PFC and DC/DC...I need to simulate the charger as a whole so that I can tune the PFC for the DC/DC converter load since it has been designed for a resistive load. If I save the ripple from PFC simulation, I won't be able to observe the response of PFC to the DC/DC converter load.

Comment: @needbrainscratched Changing the battery's capacity will allow you to charge with the same current and get the job done faster, since changing the capacity means changing a time constant. Also, there should be no spaces in the name when using the ping operator, `@<TAB>`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Changing the battery capacity is changing the nominal current drawn by the battery. I believe that maybe a built in  feature of the battery model in simulink. If you know of a way to get around it please let me know, or if there is any other equivalent model of battery I can use where the current limit is independent of the battery capacity.

Comment: Averaged converter modelling is perfect for this. i.e. the dynamics of the converter are averaged over a single switching cycle. You should also check out PLECS standalone - much faster for simulating switched converters.

Comment: @needbrainscratched I don't have Matlab so I can't tell you if you can or cannot change the battery model, but changing the capacity doesn't mean less current, or more, since the current is dictated by the load. Or charger, in this case. There's nothing stopping you from charging a 1 mF cap with a 1 A just as you would a 1 F; the result will be 1000x less time.